# Text-decoration: none does not work with Rails links

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, text-decorations

I have 2 links with Glyphicons and want Text-decoration: none; But for some reason it wont disappear, i'm getting always a hover Line.

The Links are:

```
<p class="user-profile-social-links pull-right">
  <% if @user.facebooklink.present? %>
      <%= link_to @user.facebooklink, title: "Facebook", :target => '_blank' do %>
          <i class="icon-facebook-sign"></i>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <% if @user.twitterlink.present? %>
      <%= link_to @user.twitterlink, title: "Twitter", :target => '_blank' do %>
          <i class="icon-twitter-sign"></i>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

And the class has this CSS:

```css
.user-profile-social-links {
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
color: #777;
}
```

Am i doing something wrong ? why isn't it working ?

**EDIT: **
This is what i'm still getting -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCFKZ.jpg (Zoom a little bit in to see the line beneath the icon)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Gareth is right.
There however may be a style that overrides this one.

Try adding `!important`:

```css
.user-profile-social-links a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: #777;
}
```

Comment: Be careful using `!important` because if you don't use it correctly or don't know how it will behave it can have undesired styling on other elements [When Using !important is the Right Choice](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) check the link out is just a quick tutorial and some info on how it behaves and what it does.

Comment: The fact that it works, actually says that its overwritten somewhere. Meaning, check the rest of your code! Cause I agree on Samuel Lopez' comment!

Answer (score 2):

You're setting these styles on your `p.user-profile-social-links`, and `p` elements already have no text-decoration, so this part of the rule actually does nothing.

You need to apply some of these styles on the `a` elements inside your `p`:

```css
.user-profile-social-links a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #777;
}

.user-profile-social-links {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: i tried this :( but im getting the line beneath anyways -> http://imgur.com/raC362u (Zoom a little bit in)

Answer (score 1):

Links have a default text-decoration and could be changed by placing this anywhere on your application.css :

```
a:-webkit-any-link {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: auto;
}
```